# AdMob ads taking up all screen space

Tags: android, layout, background, admob

After long hours of problems with getting ads to work it finally works.
But now my AdMob ads add a black background in its view/layout(I don't know)
So my game isn't visible anymore. The size of the ad itself is exactly how I want it,
but I need to get rid of this weird black background.

I suspect that I'm doing something wrong with layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4118138803752321/8641047294"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a `RelativeLayout` please assign the position of the `AdView` and that should take care of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the position for your Adview within the RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4118138803752321/8641047294"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```